# Google PhoneNumber Validator Not Validating Correctly

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

I'm trying to implement [google](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber)'s phone number validation, it btw does the formatting for some numbers using this snippet of code

```
$("#phone").unbind().keyup(function () {
    var val_old = $(this).val();
    var newString = new libphonenumber.AsYouType('US').input(val_old);
    $(this).focus().val('').val(newString);
});
```

but when it comes to validation it returns `false` for numbers which clearly look legit

```
$('#phone').val();
"0796321811"
var phone_no = $('#phone').val();
undefined
libphonenumber.isValidNumber(phone_no)
false
libphonenumber.isPossibleNumber(phone_no)
false
$('#phone').val();
"(451) 552-7744"
var phone_no = $('#phone').val();
undefined
libphonenumber.isValidNumber(phone_no)
false
```

Comment: Why is `var phone_no = $('#phone').val()` `undefined` and `$('#phone').val();` is not?

Comment: @xcy7e the console returns `undefined` when you assign the response to a variable on chrome

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the current version of `libphonenumber`? I found different documentations for different versions having different requirements.

Try with region code

```
libphonenumber.isValidNumber({
  "country_code": 41,
  "national_number": 0796321811
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://catamphetamine.github.io/libphonenumber-js/legacy.html) for the new legacy api:

It says `valid: false` for `0796321811` so I assume it's not your fault. You either need more information to feed the api with or the number is indeed invalid(?). I don't see any way to get more information out of the API, so to say why it is seen invalid. Most sites I know ask for a region code too to simplify number verification, is that something you could implement?

Comment: so the issue seems like you need to put the country code first, I'll need to look into how to disable that and provide two country codes as input